# Sending 'Shipping Profiles' to Google Sheets using Shopify's API?

Tags: google-sheets, shopify, shopify-api

Would it be possible to use Shopify's API to send each of our Shipping Profiles (including all products by title and/or sku) to a separate Google Sheets file and have them synced one way from Shopify to Google Sheets? I know Shopify's API now allows for access to (delivery profiles) so exporting 'Shipping Profiles' is possible I just don't know if sending this data to Google Sheets (per our requirement) is possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has API calls for your account, so you should be able to do that. At the very least, it is a very easy thing to export data from Shopify like that, and format it as CSV, which you can then import to Google sheets if you cannot figure out their API for sheets.

Comment: I understand now. One more question. If I pull the data from the Shopify API directly into Google Sheets using the API Connector for sheets will this also pull in data from apps we are using? For example, if we use a 'Shipping App' instead of Shopify's Native Shipping Profiles can we pull shipping rates from that app using Shopify's API 'ShippingZone' resource?

Comment: I doubt it, but you never know. Most private or custom Apps reveal nothing to you about their inner machinations.

Answer (score 0):

[google-drive-ruby](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby) gem is a wrapper for Google Drive API, this is all you need to interact with Google sheets from Ruby land. Good luck!